# Excel: Lookup multiple values and list them in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, vlookup

Let's say I have an Excel table listing books by authors in column A and B. In columns "Adam" and "Alice" a book gets an "x" if a character with that name occurs in the book.

| Column A | Column B | Adam | Alice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Title1 | Author1 |  | x |
| Title2 | Author2 | x |  |
| Title3 | Author1 | x |  |

In another table I have a column with all names (i.e. Adam and Alice). I now want to find all the books that contains the specific name and list them in a single cell with commas, like so:

| Names | In books |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | Title2 by Author2, Title3 by Author1 |
| Alice | Title1 by Author1 |

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem. Do I have to use VBA or could I use nested functions? I thought I could use MATCH and perhaps `TEXTJOIN()` inside some kind of IF function or loop, but I don't know how. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Filter Excel Table Data

MS365

```
=IFNA(TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(
    Table1[Titles]&" by "&Table1[Authors],
    CHOOSECOLS(Table1,XMATCH([@Names],Table1[#Headers]))="x",
    "No titles!")),"Not listed!")
```

For Excel 2021, replace `CHOOSECOLS(Table1,XMATCH([@Names],Table1[#Headers]))="x",` with

```
INDEX(Table1,0,XMATCH([@Names],Table1[#Headers]))="x",
```

For Excel 2019, replace `CHOOSECOLS(Table1,XMATCH([@Names],Table1[#Headers]))="x",` with

```
INDEX(Table1,0,MATCH([@Names],Table1[#Headers],0))="x",
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in `B7` and copy down:

```
=TEXTJOIN({" by ";", "},,FILTER($A$2:$B$4,INDEX($C$2:$D$4,,MATCH($A7,C$1:D$1,0))="x"))
```

In `A7`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(C$1:D$1)
```

Answer (score 1):

*There are many ways to work on this, but in terms of **flexibility**, I would use `POWER QUERY` here which can **effortlessly** do the automation thus saving **time and effort**. `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`*.

**Method Using `Excel Formulas`** --> Applicable To `MS365`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN({" by ";", "},,TAKE(FILTER(Authorstbl,
  CHOOSECOLS(Authorstbl,XMATCH([@Names],Authorstbl[#Headers]))="x",""),,2))
```

---

Following Applicable To `Excel 2019`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(Authorstbl[Titles]&" by "&Authorstbl[Authors],
  INDEX(Authorstbl,,MATCH([@Names],Authorstbl[#Headers],0))="x",""))
```

---

**Method using `POWER QUERY`**

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Authorstbl`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Authorstbl"]}[Content],
    UnpivotOtherCols = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Titles", "Authors"}, "Names", "Value"),
    RemoveCols = Table.RemoveColumns(UnpivotOtherCols,{"Value"}),
    MergeCols = Table.CombineColumns(RemoveCols,{"Titles", "Authors"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" by ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    GroupRowsAndJoin = Table.Group(MergeCols, {"Names"}, {{"In Books", each Text.Combine([Merged],", "), type text}}),
    Sorted = Table.Sort(GroupRowsAndJoin,{{"Names", Order.Ascending}})
in
    Sorted
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Answer (score 1):

This is an option with a single formula that moves and shakes with the data as it grows...

```
=LET(
  KeyColumnCount, 2,
  JustNames, TRANSPOSE(DROP(TAKE(DataTable[#All], 1), , KeyColumnCount)),
  NamesWithTitles, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(JustNames), 1, LAMBDA(r,c,
      LET(
        FilteredData, FILTER(DataTable, INDEX(DataTable[#Data], , r+KeyColumnCount) = "x"),
        KeyColumns, TAKE(FilteredData, , 2),
        ConcatenatedKeys, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(KeyColumns), 1, LAMBDA(r,c, TEXTJOIN(" by ", FALSE, CHOOSEROWS(KeyColumns, r)))),
        AllConcatenated, TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, ConcatenatedKeys),
      AllConcatenated))),
  FinalData, HSTACK(JustNames, NamesWithTitles),
FinalData)
```

... you just need to name your table of data to be `DataTable` (which is easily changed if you want to use something different to that)

FYI, there are a couple of (very) small points that could be done better but I'd already taken the screenshot so couldn't be bothered changing it.

Will require a fairly up to date version of Excel.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=MAP(F2:F3,LAMBDA(s,TEXTJOIN({" by ",", "},,REPT(A2:B4,XLOOKUP(s,C1:D1,C2:D4)="x"))))
```